# How can i delete a drawn circle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my method for drawing on the touch screen.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    path.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // nothing to do
                    path.addCircle(lastdownx,lastdowny,0,Path.Direction.CW);
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            // Schedules a repaint.
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

When i click on the screen down once it's drawing a circle.
I want to do when i remove my finger ACTION_UP it will delete the drawn circle.

The way i'm doing it now does nothing to the drawn circle.

Comment: reset the path in ACTION_UP case

Comment: The reset delete everything. And i want to delete only the circle.

Comment: Then keep a separate path for the things you want to keep and reset just the path with the circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two different paths.

**One** for the line you are drawing.

**Second** one for the circle which you want to follow your finger.

This way you can only reset the path that is keeping your circle data, and leave the line path.

### Here is a code example:

```
private Path pathSave = new Path(); //The path for the circle you wish to save.
```

You can use the same paint for the circle if you wish, but I tweaked my example a bit and I added a different paint and size for the circle.

```
private Paint paintCircle = new Paint();
paintCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
paintCircle.setStrokeWidth(20);
paintCircle.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
paintCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paintCircle.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
```

In the `onDraw` method you want to draw both paths like so:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(pathSave ,paintCircle);
}
```

For the logic:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY); //Only paint the line path.
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                pathSave.reset(); //Reset the circle.
                pathSave.addCircle(eventX,eventY,50,Path.Direction.CW); //Draw circle
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                pathSave.reset(); //On lifting finger circle dissapears.
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this fits what you are looking for.